# protobuf-net inheritance with generic type

Tags: generics, inheritance, serialization, protobuf-net

I'm having some problems trying to perform a deserialize using protobuf-net when using a more complex hierarchy involving also generics and inheritance.

What is the way to define dynamically the type hierarchy?

Interesting thing is that the serialization works fine, but the deserialization fails with an exception with the message: "It was not possible to prepare a serializer for: Serialization.command.ICommand"

See bellow the code I'm using:

```
    [ProtoContract]
public abstract class AbstractEntity
{

    public AbstractEntity()
    {

    }
    protected AbstractEntity(int integer)
    {
        this.integer = integer;
    }

    private int noSerializable = 0;
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int NoSerializable { get { return noSerializable; }
        set { noSerializable=value; }
    }
}


[ProtoContract]
public class Entity:AbstractEntity
{
    public Entity() : base()
    {

    }
    public Entity(int integer) : base(integer)
    {
    }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public String Surname { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public interface ICommand
{
    void Execute();
}

[ProtoContract]
public abstract class AbstractCommand: ICommand
{
    public  abstract void someAbstractMet();
    public  void Execute()
    {

    }
}

[ProtoContract]
public  class AbstractEntityCommand<T>:AbstractCommand where T:AbstractEntity
{

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public T Entity { set; get; }

    public AbstractEntityCommand()
    {

    } 
    public AbstractEntityCommand(T entity)
    {
        Entity = entity;
    }

    public override void someAbstractMet()
    {

    }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class UpdateEntityCommand<T>:AbstractEntityCommand<T> where T:AbstractEntity
{
    public UpdateEntityCommand()
    {

    } 

    public UpdateEntityCommand(T entity):base(entity)
    {

    } 
    public override void someAbstractMet()
    {

    }

}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        var entity = new Entity(4);
       Console.WriteLine("Using Protobuf");
        //first define dinamicaly the hierarchy -  see ProtoInclude attribute
        RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof (AbstractEntity), true).AddSubType(7, typeof (Entity));
        AbstractEntity absEnt = entity;
        bites = absEnt.ProtoBufSerialize();

        thirdEntity = (Entity)bites.ProtoBufDeserialize<AbstractEntity>();
        Console.WriteLine("Name=" + thirdEntity.Name + "   Surname=" + thirdEntity.Surname + "  Age=" + thirdEntity.Age + "   integer=" + thirdEntity.TheInt + " No serializable field = " + thirdEntity.NoSerializable);

       // Console.ReadKey();

        Console.WriteLine("Test for generics");

        RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(ICommand), true).AddSubType(70, typeof(AbstractCommand));

        RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(ICommand), true).AddSubType(80, typeof(AbstractEntityCommand<>));
        RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(ICommand), true).AddSubType(90, typeof(UpdateEntityCommand<>));

        ICommand genCommand = new UpdateEntityCommand<Entity>(entity);


       bites =  genCommand.ProtoBufSerialize();
        var concreteCmd = bites.ProtoBufDeserialize<UpdateEntityCommand<Entity>>();
        var unknownCmd = bites.ProtoBufDeserialize<ICommand>();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

All works fine until I try to deserialize the ICommand.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Generics aren't the problem, protobuf-net supports those. The problem is that you have an interface as a root object. While it's perfectly fine to serialize interfaces as members, it's not possible for an interface to act as the root object.

Therefore

```
bites.ProtoBufDeserialize<ICommand>();
```

throws an exception.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. Even if the root is an abstract class, the behavior is the same. Any other ideas?